# simple method to completely backup Debian over network

Tags: backup, debian

I need to completely backup Debian 5.0 over network (internet) to my Windows machine. Later I'm going to switch device to identical one and restore Linux there. I access Linux by ssh and sftp. What a fast and simple approach would you recommend? Please also specify how to restore if it's not obvious.

Comment: maybe just tar/gzip root filesystem and store the file. Then install same distro and restore your archive to root. I'd skip at least /proc and /dev when restoring. Also I'd first back-up the NEW distro in the same way prior to restoring your OLD one - so when something broke you can roll back and start over. Also be careful not to broke your ability to ssh while you restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clonezilla - http://clonezilla.org/

Backup

- Download iso
- Burn onto CD/DVD or FLASH.
- Boot Linux systems to clonezilla cd/dvd
- Use device to image - backup entire linux disk to a file(s) on your windows system.
- Select samba server for the image directory and enter the Windows server name or IP
- Select savedisk

Restore

- Boot Linux systems to clonezilla cd/dvd
- Use device to image
- Select samba server for the image directory and enter the Windows server name or IP
- Select restoredisk